# Eclipse makefile build is slow... What gives?

Tags: linux, eclipse, performance, makefile, eclipse-cdt

We are avid Eclipse fans -- it is fantastic! But we have about 40 c++ projects (and growing), and building all of these projects, when all projects are up-to-date, takes about half a minute (total). If I were to simply create a bash script that executed "make all" on all 40 projects, it would execute in way less than a second.

Eclipse seems to want to run a test for the proper tools each time by executing:

```
g++ -E -P -v -dD /myfolder/.metada/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp
```

where specs.cpp is an empty file. This step seems to be taking most of the build time.

Any insight here from anyone? Any way to tell Eclipse to trust the tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to experiment with [C/C++ Build Discovery options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_build_discovery.htm) page of your projects properties. The first thing that I would try is to turn off "**Enable generate scanner info command**" option.

[image: Discovery Options]

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the perfect response. Build time has been reduced by over 10x.

Comment: Actually, build time went from 30 seconds to a few milliseconds. So speed up was over 100x. Thanks again!!

Comment: this tab is no longer available with eclipse kepler and the functionality has been deprecated. What should we do then? Thanks.

Comment: @HAL9000 I'm afraid, I can't help you with Eclipse, because I use Sublime Text now.