# Eclipse Mars 2 slow build of C++ projects (Linux)

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, build, cocos2d-x

I wanted to switch from Netbeans to Eclipse to work on a C++ project under GNU-Linux.

Eclipse is great but I noticed that the build time is MUCH higher than Netbeans.

I did a benchmark on a Cocos2d-x (game framework) C++ empty project:

- Terminal (bash)      : 1 minute and 37 secs
- Netbeans (8.0.2)     : 1 minute and 48 secs
- Eclipse (Mars2 4.5.2): approximately 10-15 minutes

in both cases CPU seems to go to 100% of load

The only build customization I did in both case is to make the compilation multi-thread (make option '-j12', i have an esacore cpu with hyper threading).

In Eclipse already tried to:

- disable indexer
- disable build log

But nothing work!

Do you have any clue?

Thanks

EDIT: I found this
[Eclipse makefile build is slow... What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770965/eclipse-makefile-build-is-slow-what-gives)

But I don't see C/C++ Build Discovery options in Mars2!

Comment: Probably just the way that eclipse builds its projects, however I highly doubt that a normal project would take 10-15 minutes under correct circumstances. Odd.

Comment: The project I used in the benchmarks is made by hundreds of c++ files! its build could take 10-15 minutes (or more)  on less power cpu or if its compiled with one thread!

Comment: I will tell you this, the way C++ Eclipse has been treating me lately, its absolutely useless. I only ever get usability out of the Java side.